# spring boot views not working without file extension?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring Boot, I have files under `webapp` resource folder, `login.xhtml`, `index.xhtml`, `register.xhtml` they are working fine with `http://localhost:8080/login.xhtml`, `http://localhost:8080/register.xhtml`, `http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml` but they are not working without the file extension, `http://localhost:8080/login`, `http://localhost:8080/index`, `http://localhost:8080/register` gives error for `/login`.

> Request URI: /login Ajax request: No Status code: 500 Exception type:
> class org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException Message: Request
> processing failed; nested exception is
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
> template [login], template might not exist or might not be accessible
> by any of the configured Template Resolvers

My `application.properties` is configured propertly:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/webapp/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.xhtml
```

Controller for login:

```
public class LoginController {
     @GetMapping("/login")
          public String login()
          {
            return "login";
          }
}
```

I wan to access both with extension and without extension. `localhost:8080/login` and `localhost:8080/login.xhtml` should work.
you comments and solutions could solve my problem.

Comment: Your app isn't configured correctly. You are probably using a `war` and not `jar` which means there is no `webapp` (in the end when packaged). When doing `http://localhost:8080/login.xhtml` it directly resolves the template as a file and totally ignores the controller, when using `/login` it gets the controller with a wrongly configured resolver. Remove the `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` and move your templates to the `src/main/resources/templates/` directory.

Comment: i have moved the file under webapp to under templates  the url works fine without extension but the css and images are not loading though i move all these to static folder under src/main/resources. what can be the reason behind? any hint

Comment: Without seeing more of your setup that will be impossible to answer (and is in fact a different question). But I would say it probably is due to the URL in your template which resolves to the wrong one.

Comment: under src/main/resource, i have static and templates folder,  under static i have css file that i copied from webapp folder, when i access the css file directly on url, localhost:8080/css/theme.css ,  doest appear but when i access using the same method from webapp folder it lists the css,  the same is for images and other files

Comment: because you should access `/static/css/theme.css`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many path links to a single controller action, e.g.

```
    @RequestMapping(path = {"/login", "/login.xhtml"})
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
```

Also, don't forget to add `@Controller` annotation to your class.